# How to find the product $\Pi_{n=1 }^\infty (1+x^{2n-1 })$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$\Pi_{n=1 }^\infty (1+x^{2n-1 })$

**Definition:** $\Pi_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$ is said to converge to $l\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$ if the limit $\Pi_{k=1}^n f(k)\to l$ as $n\to \infty$ and we write $\Pi_{n=1 }^\infty (1+x^{2n-1 })=l$.

I tried to find the product as below but got stuck.

For brevity let's say $a_n=1+x^{2n-1 }$. Now for $\Pi_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ to converge we must have $a_n=\frac{\Pi a_n}{\Pi a_{n-1}}\to 1$. It follows that $|x|\lt 1$.

Let $P_n=\Pi_{k=1}^n a_k$. It follows that $\frac {\ln P_n}{n}\to 0$ ($n$th term of a sequence tends to $0\implies $ arithmetic means of $n$ elements converges to $0$ ).

$\therefore$ Given any $\epsilon\gt 0$, we'll have $|\ln P_n|\lt \epsilon n$ for sufficiently large values of $n$ and then $e^{-\epsilon n}\lt P_n\lt e^{\epsilon n}$. Stuck.

How do I proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: @VivaanDaga:  Note that for $|x|\lt 1, |x|^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: See : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html

Comment: @JJacquelin: Thanks for response. It seems that the limit of $P_n$ as $n\to \infty$, can't be represented by an elementary function.

Comment: OK. But it depends on what is a special function. The p-Pochhammer Symbol could be named p-Pochhammer Function and standardized as special function.

Comment: This is related to Ramanujan class invariant $G_m$. Your product converges for $|x|<1$. If $x=e^{-\pi\sqrt{m}}$ where $m$ is a positive rational number then $G_m=2^{-1/4}x^{-1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x^{2n-1})$ is an algebraic real number and one can evaluate this in closed form with some effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you show convergence:

- $\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+x^{2k-1})$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathrm{log}(1+x^{2k-1})$ converges.
- for all positive $x$, you have the bound $|\log(1+x^{2k-1})| \le |x^{2k-1}|$
- $\sum_k x^{2k-1}$ is (absolutely) convergent for all $|x|<1$ (just a geometric series). So the original series converges too.

For $|x|\ge1$ you already showed that the product cannot possibly converge. Which leaves open the case $x\in(-1,0)$. I think the most elegant thing to do here so to rewrite the original product into a power-series. Than you know that it must have a convergence radius equal in the positive and negative direction. It follows that the original expression converges exactly if $|x|<1$.

For the value it converges to, look for 'Pochhammer Symbol' (as @JJacquelin noted).

Comment: Thanks for response :) My problem is not to show convergence. The problem is to find the value of the product.

Comment: Tex hint ... use `\prod` not `\Pi`.  Get $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+x^{2k-1})$$ not $$\Pi_{k=1}^\infty(1+x^{2k-1})$$.

Comment: There is no elementary expression fo the 'q Pochhammer Symbol', so there is most likely also no elementary expression for this value. Of course it is easy enough to numerically compute the value for any given $x$.

Comment: @Simon: I see. So it seems that there is no elementary expression for the limit of $P_n$. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(x) := \prod_{n=1 }^\infty (1+x^{2n-1 }),\qquad x \in \mathbb C, |x| < 1
$$
Converges to a holomorphic function.  This is not an "elementary function".  It can be written in terms of some known special functions.

**added**
For example, the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) is
$$
\eta(q) = q^{1/24}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)
$$
This means
$$
f(x) = \frac{\eta(-x)}{\eta(x^2)}\;(-x)^{1/24}
$$
Some values of $\eta$ are known in closed form.  So we can compute some values of $f(x)$.  Examples (writing $q=-x, q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$):

With $\tau = \frac{i}{2}$ we get
$$
f(-e^{-\pi}) = 2^{1/8} e^{-\pi/24} \approx 0.9567087254
$$
With $\tau = \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt3}{6}$ we get
$$
f(e^{-\pi/\sqrt3}) = 2^{1/3} e^{-\pi\sqrt3/72} \approx 1.168211663
$$
With $\tau = i\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$ we get
$$
f(-e^{-\pi\sqrt{10}}) = 2^{1/4}\;
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/2}\;e^{\pi\sqrt{10}/24}
\approx 0.9999515311
$$

Comment: Thank for response:). I think that it makes sense that $f(x)$ is not an elementary function as @JJacquelin also hinted through comment.